# Espresso Android, clicking on WebView elements error

Tags: android, webview, android-espresso

I am using Espresso for my instrumentation tests. I am using newest Espresso lib supporting WebView:

https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/web/

I used to work with webViews on Espresso and I managed to make it work. But this time I am not sure if it's possible. There is a spinner inside webView, you click on it and it should display list of items. I have problem with clicking on that spinner. WebView source code:

```
    <div class="row select-box">
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <label for="MultipaysSessionSenderBankCode" class="inline">Bank name</label>    </div>
    <div class="medium-8 columns">
        <input type="hidden" name="data[MultipaysSession][sender_bank_code]" id="" value=""><select name="data[MultipaysSession][sender_bank_code]" class="hide-first" data-toggler="" data-value="other" data-show="other-bank" id="MultipaysSessionSenderBankCode">
<option value="">Please select your bank</option>
<option value="00000">Demo Bank</option>
<optgroup label="Top banks">
<option value="24900005">Alior Bank</option>
<option value="10900004">Bank Zachodni WBK (plus d. Kredyt Bank)</option>
<option value="10500103">ING Bank Śląski</option>
<option value="11402004">mBank</option>
<option value="11400000">mBank (d. MultiBank)</option>
<option value="11602202">Millennium Bank</option>
<option value="12401428">Pekao (UniCredit)</option>
<option value="10200003">PKO BP (iPKO, iPKONET)</option>
<option value="10205558">PKO BP (Inteligo)</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Other banks">
<option value="20300003">Bank BGŻ</option>
<option value="10600005">Bank BPH</option>
<option value="13200006">Bank Pocztowy</option>
<option value="19300005">Bank BPS (E25)</option>
<option value="16000003">BNP Paribas (d. Fortis Bank)</option>
<option value="15401056">BOŚ Bank</option>
<option value="10300022">Citibank Handlowy</option>
<option value="19400008">Credit Agricole (d. Lukas Bank)</option>
<option value="19101048">Deutsche Bank</option>
<option value="14700002">Eurobank</option>
<option value="14600009">Getin Bank</option>
<option value="16800007">PLUS Bank (d. INVEST-BANK)</option>
<option value="17500009">Raiffeisen Polbank</option>
<option value="24901044">T-Mobile Usługi Bankowe (d. Alior Sync)</option>
<option value="21300004">Volkswagen Bank</option>
</optgroup>
<option value="other">Other ...</option>
</select>   </div>
</div>
```

And now I want to locate this spinner in Espresso and click on it (it will show me android dialog with items). I try something like that:

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "MultipaysSessionSenderBankCode")).perform(webClick());
```

or,

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "data[MultipaysSession][sender_bank_code]")).perform(webClick());
```

Locator documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/web/webdriver/Locator.html

But I whatever I try I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal exception checking document state: Evaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
} hasMessage: true message: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
```

Does that mean that there is some kind of security preventing me to touch this view with espresso?

Comment: Have you found any solution to it?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't touched the problem for a long time but I will need to return to it soon. If I find out something I will inform you.

Comment: I'm also wondering if a solution was found to this. Any news?

Answer (score 0):

Your id tag is empty. Consider doing this

```
> <div class="medium-8 columns">
>     <input type="hidden" name="data[MultipaysSession][sender_bank_code]" id="MyIdForThisUI"
> value=""><select name="data[MultipaysSession][sender_bank_code]"
> class="hide-first" data-toggler="" data-value="other"
> data-show="other-bank" id="MultipaysSessionSenderBankCode">
```

And then:

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "MyIdForThisUI")).perform(webClick());
```